# Is CreateMutex process-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, mutex

I'm creating a named mutex from two processes and I am checking if the named mutex already existed.

Is it possible that both calls to CreateMutex will return a "new" mutex (not process/thread-safe)?

Answer (score 3):

It would be pointless for a such a mutex (which *can* be used inter-process) to not be "process-safe"!

Such is implied in [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx):

> .. If the mutex is a *named* mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object.
>
> Two or more processes can call CreateMutex to create the same named mutex. The first process actually creates the mutex, and *subsequent processes [..] simply open a handle to the existing mutex*. This enables multiple processes to get handles of the same mutex ..
>
> *Multiple processes can have handles of the same mutex object*, enabling use of the object for interprocess synchronization ..